# How can I synchronize Google contacts and calendar with Palm Centro and Outlook 2000?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, google-calendar, google-contacts, palm

Seeking a free solution to synchronize my calendar and contacts between my Palm Centro and Google contacts and calendar. I currently sync my Palm contacts and calendar with Outlook 2000 on Windows XP.

[Google Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955) does not support Outlook 2000, and I would rather not pay to upgrade Outlook just for this, as I don't even use Outlook much anymore. I wouldn't mind migrating my calendar and contacts off of it, as long as I can still sync with the Palm.

I don't have an unlimited data plan for my Centro, so I can't use a solution that wirelessly syncs directly to Google.

I have set up [GCALDaemon](http://gcaldaemon.sourceforge.net) to sync up my Google calendar with multiple machines running [Rainlendar](http://www.rainlendar.net), but I have not yet figured out a way to synchronize that data with the Palm.

Answer (score 1):

I use MemoToo that supports all of your options. In addition all of your contacts are stored in the cloud and you can get the same list of contacts anywhere.

I wrote a long blog post on [syncing all of my contacts](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth.aspx) with a wide veriety of platforms.

Answer (score 0):

[Evolution](http://www.dipconsultants.com/evolution/) is a (free) Outlook-like program for Linux that has been ported to Windows. I use the Linux version and it syncs my google calendar and my Palm T3.